# TypeError: jsxRuntime is undefined

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, jsx, webpack-4, tsx

I am trying to render a React component built using tsx in a AngularJS application.My AngularJS app uses babel and webpack 4. Meanwhile, the library build includes **require('react/jsx-runtime')**, which probably will be part of the problem, but needed

Here is my .babelrc file:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
        ["@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx", {
            "runtime": "automatic"
        }]
    ]
}
```

Here is my package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.14.7",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.14.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.15.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.6.0",
```

Finally, my webpack configuration includes the following rules:

```
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        exclude: ['/node_modules/'],
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-typescript']
          }
        }
      },
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated